# Import reviews from Amazon

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, product-review

[M1]

We are selling some products on Amazon that we are selling on our website. We have plenty of reviews on multiple items, and we'd like to import those reviews on our Magento site. I have successfully exported reviews from amazon in .csv and they are in this format:

SKU
Customer Nickname
Title
Review description
Rating (please note that exported rating has only one value which is average of all the attributes - shipping, delivery time, product as per description, etc.)

How can I import it to my Magento 1 site?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be custom. Probably something similar to the following

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12256318/10121426